# How to add JVM options?

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm

I'm having some issue with Android Studio, and I've read a potential solution (or at least a path to a solution) would be to add the option to the JVM

-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash

I tried using the terminal in Android Studio, and I tried adding it as an environment variable, but even reading the Oracle website, I'm simply lost

Comment: Edited the launch configuration?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ah! That is the process I needed. Now if only doing this was the solution to my bigger problem, but it seems as if I'm still stuck

Comment: Open a new question. Take great care in crafting it or you will not get the response you want.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I actually have one open that I asked previously, I just couldn't for the life of me figure this one out, and I thought it would help be a solution.